# C#: how to insert string containing new lines into TextBox?

Tags: c#, textbox, newline

How do you insert a string containing new lines into a TextBox?

When I do this using `\n` as the new line character, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You have to set the multiline property of the textbox to true and you can use

```
Environment.NewLine
```

as the new line char.

You can also use \r\n  instead of Environment.NewLine

```
TextBox1.Text = "First line\r\nSecond line"
```

Answer (score 8):

As the other answers say you have to set `.Multiline = true`, but I don't think you then *have* to use the `Lines` property. If you already have the text as one string you can then assign it to the `Text` property as normal. If your string contains '\n' as separators you can do a replace to the current system's newline:

```
textBox1.Text = myString.Replace("\n", Environment.NewLine);
```

Answer (score 4):

The first method is:

```
textbox1.Text = "First " + System.Environment.NewLine + " Second";
```

The second method is:

```
textbox1.Text = "First \r\n Second";
```

Answer (score 1):

First, set the TextBox.Multiline property to true. Then you can assign the TextBox.Lines property to an array of strings.

```
textbox.Lines = s.Split('\n');
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you need to set the [TextBox.Multiline](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox.multiline(VS.90).aspx) property to true.

Then you need to get the text into the text box, you have two options for this.

- Set the lines as an array of strings:

  [textbox.Lines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.lines(v=VS.90).aspx) = s.Split('\n');
- Otherwise you need to use the windows line end (“\r\n”) rather than the unix/c line end (“n”) when setting the text.  This can be done using [Environment.NewLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline.aspx) if you wish to make the code a bit clearer.

  textBox1.Text = myString.Replace("\n", Environment.NewLine);

If you wish your code to cope with both types of line ends, then you can strips out the “\r” before doing one of the above.   *Line terminators in stings are still a lot larger pain then they should be!*