# Random Sequence to Deterministic Sequence (based on the contents of textbox)

Tags: c#, arrays, random, game-engine

I'm making a Simon Says game, but unlike normal Simon Says games (where random sequences are generated each time), I wish to make the sequences non-random and based on `textbox1.text` due to the nature of the game.

So for example: `textbox1.text` may include the line "RYRG". Which the game interprets as "Red, Yellow, Red, Green".

At the moment, the game randomly generates a sequence each time. I'm a bit stuck as to how I can change this. Essentially, I want to put the contents of the textbox `textbox1.text` into an Array. So that this Array would then serve as the sequence buffer for the game. Any help is appreciated, thank you in advance.

**Update: it all works now (but for 1 line only)**

Code:

```
private Color[] sequence;
//Declare dictionary
private Dictionary<char,Color>  stringTocolor = new Dictionary<char,Color>();

public SimonSays ()
{
    //add content to Dictionary
    stringTocolor.Add('R', Color.Red);
    stringTocolor.Add('G', Color.Green);
    stringTocolor.Add('B', Color.Blue);
    stringTocolor.Add('Y', Color.Yellow);

    Color[] colourset = newSequence(textBox1.Text.Length);
}

public Color[] newSequence(int length)
{
    Color[] array = new Color[length];
    //check dictionary has the char key or not
    for (int i = 0; i < textBox1.Text.Length; i++)
    {
        if (stringTocolor.ContainsKey(textBox1.Text[i]))
        {
             array[i] = stringTocolor[textBox1.Text[i]];
        }
        //give alert if wrong key
        else
        {
             MessageBox.Show("Wrong Colour input at index " + i + " of textbox string!");
        }
    }
    this.sequence = array;
    return array;
}
```

Could I possibly utilise this line?

```
        public void newSequence (Color [] sequence)
    {
    this.sequence= //read next line 

    }
```

Comment: What you meant of multi-line? Multi-line in textbox actually still one string in the textbox just after the string exceed one line length then it goes to next line,it is still a string,or you want split the string four char by four char to different array?

Comment: Ahh that makes sense. Yes that's it! Sorry, I couldn't word my question properly. Splitting the string by 4 char by 4 char to different array sounds like the solution.

Comment: use this? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.linecount%28v=vs.110%29.aspx
Use the `textBox.LineCount;` get line number and `textBox.GetLineText(line)` to get each line? so if you have 10 lines, you want to have 10 arrays? the arrays put inside another array or list? each line must have 4 colours or can be less than 4 colours?

Comment: Thank you so much! That's perfect. I'll test it out, It'll always be 4 colors :D

Comment: Thank you so much, I really appreciate your help. I pasted the full source code here: http://pastebin.com/hzvcPXAf

Comment: I check the code and I saw no reference on the method `GetLinesCollectionFromTextBox()`, I tried make textbox input multi-line with "textBox1.Text = "RGBY\r\nBYGR";" by refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3403731/c-how-to-insert-string-containing-new-lines-into-textbox , but then my code have error.May be your data multi-line is not created somewhere else, anyway, thanks for share

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Latest

I tried to use Dictionary for matching the char to Color to shorten the matching source code part. Then pass TextBox instead of its length.

```
private Color[] sequence;
//Declare dictionary
private Dictionary<char,Color>  stringTocolor = new Dictionary<char,Color>();

public SimonSays ()
{
    //add content to Dictionary
    stringTocolor.Add('R', Color.Red);
    stringTocolor.Add('G', Color.Green);
    stringTocolor.Add('B', Color.Blue);
    stringTocolor.Add('Y', Color.Yellow);

    Color[] colourset = newSequence(textBox1);
}

public Color[] newSequence(TextBox textBox)
{
    int length = textBox.Text.Length;
    Color[] array = new Color[length];
    //check dictionary has the char key or not
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        if (stringTocolor.ContainsKey(textBox.Text[i]))
        {
             array[i] = stringTocolor[textBox.Text[i]];
        }
        //give alert if wrong key
        else
        {
             MessageBox.Show("Wrong Colour input at index " + i + " of textbox string!");
        }
    }
    this.sequence = array;
    return array;
}
```

---

### Old

Call `newSequence`somewhere by passing the textbox text length as its argument (length)

```
Color[] colourset = newSequence(textBox1.Text.Length);
```

then try to check each character inside the textbox text then change them to corresponding colour and return them in colourset.

```
 public Color[] newSequence(int length)
 {
        Color[] array = new Color[length];
        //Random rand = new Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond);// don't inline w/ colors[] - wont be random

        for (int i = 0; i < textBox1.Text.Length; i++)
        {
            //array[i] = colors[rand.Next(0, 4)];
            if (textBox1.Text[i]=='R')
            {
                array[i] = Color.Red;
            }
            else if (textBox1.Text[i] == 'G')
            {
                array[i] = Color.Green;
            }
            else if (textBox1.Text[i] == 'B')
            {
                array[i] = Color.Blue;
            }
            else if (textBox1.Text[i] == 'Y')
            {
                array[i] = Color.Yellow;
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Wrong colour input found!");
            }

        }
        //why stored to sequence? further use in current class?
        this.sequence = array;
        return array;
    }
```

seem like you generating a class, so may be your newSequence need to have **one more argument** to receive the **textBox string** from outside of the class but **not directly** access to the textbox?

Comment: Thank you so much V-SHY! For the new code, do we need to include `for (int i = 0; i < textBox1.Text.Length; i++)` anywhere? It's saying the `i` in `[i]` does not exist in the current context.

Comment: ok, edited, `i < textBox1.Text.Length` can be replaced by `i < length`

Comment: Hi V-SHY! Sorry to bother you again. The code works wonderfully, though it only works if there is 1 line in the textbox (e.g. RGGY). If I have multiple lines, how can I make it so that, next line = new sequence? I added a new line in the code above that might help.

Comment: How your multiline input work? Join the old array? Mean if first line RGGB second line BBYG then the array becomes having 8 colours?

Comment: Multiline input is just 4 characters per line :) So the next sequence will read the next line. Instead of the same line as before.

I think perhaps it should join a new array? I'm not sure...

Comment: I think it might be that this: `Color[] colourset = newSequence(textBox1.Text.Length);` isn't anticipating a line break at index 4.

Comment: I think need to pass a textbox instead its length,but thinking how to foreach multiline input and join to sequence array